# What is the best IDE today for HTML5 for a programmer who's working with .net on the Server sider?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, html, ide

Is VS2010 support for Javascript & jQuery make it a good IDE for JS/HTML5? or are there better options?

I'm writing the server side in .Net, and that's why this is my default choice usually. if VS is not the best IDE for that - using two different IDEs won't be irritating ?

Comment: When was it Visual Studio?

Comment: Humor me. I'm a .Net developer - this is usually my first choice :)

Comment: @alecgorge Visual Studio has always been and likely will always be the best IDE.

Comment: @Josh M. Not if you use anything that isn't Windows...I use Linux, Mac and Windows on an almost daily basis so cross platform is handy.

Comment: @alecgorge - i do the developing only on windows so cross platform is not that important..

Comment: @Elad Fair enough, but my comment was more about Visual Studio being the best IDE in the past, present and future.

Comment: yeah, but i'm not really trying to open the "which is the best IDE" question - i just want to know which would be best for a .net developer doing html5/js development

Comment: @alecgorge just because you can't use Visual Studio on your Mac doesn't mean that it's not the "best IDE." Since this question is tagged with "visual-studio-2010" I figured it was safe to recommend that as a solution.

Comment: oh and BTW, you can use vs2010 on a mac quite easily - i have a developer friend that uses a mac & vs. works amazingly well over VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 added additional support for HTML 5.

Comment: how good is it? is the JS intellisense good enough?

Comment: JS intellisense is good. For instance, JQuery has an additional intellisense documentation file that gives you even more information: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js

Comment: is there any more tips a jquery/js/html developer should know? is this written somewhere? how would i have known to look there? (thank god for SO :)

Comment: Have a look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html and you will see the html_5.xsd which is used for intellisense in the IDE.

Comment: On the download page (http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) v1.4.1 has a documentation link for Visual Studio next to it. There is also one for v1.5.x but you'll have to search for it as it isn't available on JQuery's website yet.

Answer (score 3):

PHPStorm/WebStorm: http://www.jetbrains.com/index.html

HTML5 Support: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/tag/html5/

Much faster and more fluid than anything else I have used. The only hangup is that the shortcuts are not consistent with Windows defaults (they are consistent with Mac's defaults).

The autocompletetion is fantastic and incredibly quick even for large JS/PHP projects.

Comment: +1 for webstorm. Because it's awesome.

Comment: how well does it work with .net on the server side? or does it at all?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of Aptana -- It now supports html5. It's an extension of the eclipse framework and it's a nice IDE for most things web related.

http://aptana.com/products/studio3

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a full featured IDE I'm a fan of [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with [JSLint plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jslintnpp/).